# PostgreSQL refuses to update DATE column

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have a table that contains one value, `period_start TIMESTAMP NOT NULL`. I'd like to have a second column that stores the day of that timestamp.

I tried the following sql:

```
ALTER TABLE foo ADD COLUMN day DATE;

UPDATE foo SET day = period_start::DATE;

ALTER TABLE foo ALTER COLUMN day SET NOT NULL;
```

Now, when I execute the above, I get an error that `day` contains null values. Looking at the content of the table, I see that every row has `NULL` as the value of day.

However, `SELECT *, period_start::DATE FROM foo` gives me the expected result.

**Why does my `UPDATE` statement fail and how can I fix it so that the `day` column gets correctly populated?**

Comment: Unrelated, but: The general rule of thumb is: do not store information that can (easily) be derived from the existing data. And casting a `timestamp` to a `date` is an extremely cheap operation. You should rather create a view that returns that information.

Comment: There must be something you are not telling us. It works just fine for me: http://rextester.com/IJNLL45394  (ignore the time display for the date display, that's a deficiency of rextester)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I know, I want to drop the timestamp afterwards because only midnight is a valid value

Comment: Then just change the column to a date. `alter table foo alter period_start type date using period_start::date`